# "effektiv" und "effizient" in einem Satz

Tags: word-usage

Einer meiner ehemaligen Lehrer behauptete, die beiden Wörter *effektiv* und *effizient* sollten nicht in einem Satz verwendet werden. Er monierte Aussagen wie:

> Die Verwaltung des Unternehmens arbeitet zwar effektiv, aber nicht effizient.
>
> Das Programm ist zwar effektiv, berechnet die Lösung jedoch nicht effizient.

Ich sehe kein logisches Problem in diesen Sätzen. Während ich einerseits besagter Lehrkraft nicht die Kompetenz zutraue, dies zu beurteilen, möchte ich aber andererseits auch nicht ausschließen, dass ich etwas übersehen habe.

Gibt es einen Grund, obige Sätze (oder ähnliche) sprachlich zu kritisieren?

Comment: In Deinen Sätzen die, die erreichte Effizienz herausstellen, sehe ich kein Problem. Bei Sätzen wie "Er arbeitet effektiv und effizient" wirkt das effektiv überzählig.

Comment: @bummi: "In Deinen Sätzen, die die ..."

Comment: Asche auf mein Haupt ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die etymologische Beschreibung im Digitalen Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache (und auch in englischen Wörterbüchern) lässt darauf schließen, dass '[effektiv](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=effektiv&submit_button=Suche&view=1)' und '[effizient](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=effizient&submit_button=Suche&view=1)' durchaus synonym verwendet wurden, wobei 'effektiv' im Deutschen älter zu sein scheint.

Der Duden beschreibt 'effizient' als ['wirksam und wirtschaftlich'](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/effizient), es setzt Wirksamkeit bereits voraus. Insofern überlappen sich beide Wörter in der Bedeutung teilweise.

Was der Lehrer also sagte, war nicht ohne Grundlage. Ich kenne die Verwendung der beiden Wörter wie in den Beispielsätzen durchaus, würde sie aber als pointierten Formulierungstil ansehen, jedenfalls gemessen an der drögen Sachlichkeit und Präzision, die einem beim wissenschaftlichen Schreiben zur Auflage gemacht wird. Man kann ja durchaus z.B. 'wirtschaftlich' und 'wirkungsstark' schreiben, es sei denn, es geht wirklich um fachsprachlich feststehende Begriffe (Informatik, Technik, Rechnungswesen).

Answer (score 11):

Die beiden Sätze sind so, wie sie da stehen, durchaus in Ordnung. Man sollte nur - wie bei allen Wörtern - genau wissen, was sie bedeuten.

### effektiv

Da geht es darum, ein Ziel mit möglichst großer Wahrscheinlichkeit zu erreichen, bzw. es möglichst vollständig zu erreichen.

Ein Beispiel:
Ich habe Ratten im Keller entdeckt und möchte sie loswerden. Also packe ich den Keller voll Dynamit und jage den ganzen Häuserblock in die Luft. Das beseitigt die Ratten sehr effektiv.

Ich könnte auch Fallen und Giftköder auslegen, aber Ratten sind sehr intelligent und sie kriegen mit, dass ihre Familienmitglieder sterben wenn sie den Köder fressen. Einige Ratten werden also möglicherweise überleben. Daher sind Fallen und Gift weniger effektiv als das Dynamit.

Bei Effektivität geht es nur um den Grad der Zielerreichung. Die eingesetzten Mittel sind kein Kriterium.

### effizient

Hier geht es darum, die Mittel, über die ich verfüge, so einzusetzen, dass sie eine möglichst große Wirkung erzielen.

Wieder ein Beispiel:
Ich habe einen Freund, der in seinem Haus kein Wasser hat, und ich habe einen fixen Geldbetrag (sagen wir mal 5000 Euro) mit dem ich ihm helfen kann. Damit kann ich ihm ein paar Liter eines sehr teuren Nobel-Mineralwassers kaufen, oder ein paar tausend Liter eines Billig-Wassers, oder ich kann ihm das Graben eines Brunnens finanzieren, was sein Wasser-Problem dauerhaft lösen würde. Die effizienteste Lösung ist der Brunnen.

Bei Effizienz stehen die eingesetzten Mittel im Zentrum der Betrachtung.

Comment: This. Genau richtig. Effektiv und effizient haben keinerlei Überlappung.

Answer (score 2):

"Effektiv" refers to "getting the job done.

"Effizient" refers to minimizing the use of resources.

They are not really the same, unless the point of the exercise is to do a job using a minimum of resources.

Answer (score -3):

Deine Frage ist lediglich, ob es einen Grund gibt, die o. g. Sätze zu kritisieren. Und ja, den gibt es. Es gibt sogar mehrere, wobei mir im Moment nur drei einfallen:

1. Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch meint effektiv dasselbe wie effizient. Das heißt, es entsteht Redundanz
2. Abseits des allgemeinen Sprachgebrauchs wird man jedoch aufgrund der Assonanz der Wörter nur verwirrt und verkompliziert einen Satz
3. Die [Bedeutungen](http://www.zeitblueten.com/news/2009/unterschied-effizient-effektiv/) sind zu nah beieinander

Deswegen empfehle ich Folgendes:
Umschreibe das, was du sagen willst, und nutze nur ein Wort von beiden.

Edit: Aufgrund der Kommentare unter meinem Beitrag möchte ich noch einmal ausdrücklich darauf hinweisen, dass meine Stichpunkte deine Frage wohl aber beantworten. Denn die Frage ist hier nach einem Grund zur Kritik. Und Punkte zur Kritik habe ich geliefert. Spätestens beim dritten Punkt ist Kritik an der Doppelverwendung notwendig.

Comment: Da würde ich widersprechen. In der IT-Branche wird der Unterschied zwischen Effektivität und Effizienz gemacht. Ich erwarte jetzt nicht, das es jeder Mensch auf der Strasse versteht, aber als Fachjargon ist es bekannt.

Comment: wie wird oft so schön zitiert:
Effektivität: „Die richtigen Dinge tun.“
Effizienz: „Die Dinge richtig tun.“

Comment: Wieso habe ich extra allgemeiner Sprachgebrauch geschrieben wenn dann doch auf einzelne Bereiche wie die IT eingegangen wird.

Comment: Ich sehe die Verwendung nicht vorwiegenden in der IT  http://www.zeitblueten.com/news/2009/unterschied-effizient-effektiv/

Comment: Ja selbst wenn man es nicht nur auf die IT bezieht treffen meine anderen Punkte immernoch zu.