# Unterschied zwischen „effizient“ und „effektiv“

Tags: meaning, difference

Kann mir jemand an einem Beispiel den Unterschied zwischen *effizient* und *effektiv* erklären?

Comment: [Ja.](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/effizient)

Comment: Related: [“effektiv” und “effizient” in einem Satz](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6112/9551)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Du hast Mäuse im Keller deines Hauses und willst sie loswerden.

### effektiv

Die Effektivität ist der Grad der Zielerreichung. Sie ist unabhängig von den eingesetzten Mitteln.

Du packst den Keller voll Dynamit, zündest es, und sprengst dein ganzes Haus samt den umliegenden Häuserblocks weg. Auf diese Weise hast du das gesetzte Ziel (Mäuse vernichten) sehr effektiv erreicht. Besonders effizient war es aber nicht, weil der Sprengstoff sehr teuer war, und die Kosten für den Wiederaufbau des Wohn-Viertels auch noch dazu kommen. Die aufgewendeten Mittel sind sehr ineffizient eingesetzt worden.

### effizient

Bei der Effizienz wird bewertet, wie viel des Zieles du mit einer vorgegebenen Menge an Ressourcen erreichst.

Du hast nur 10 Euro und darfst nicht mehr einsetzen um die Mäuse los zu werden. Du gehst zum Jungen des Nachbarn, fragst ihn, ob du deren Katzen ausborgen darfst, sperrst sie zwei Tage lang in den Keller, und zahlst dem Jungen dafür ein Eis.

Die vorhandenen Mittel (10 Euro) wurden sehr effizient eingesetzt, um die Mäuse los zu werden. Es kann aber nicht ausgeschlossen werden, dass den Katzen die eine oder andere Maus entkommen ist. Die Katzen-Methode ist also nicht ganz so effektiv wie die Sprengung.

Comment: Wohn-Viertel? Hätte nicht gedacht das du so ein Bindestrichfan bist :)

Answer (score 5):

Effektiv - tue ich die richtige Sache?

Effizient - tue ich die Sache richtig?

Comment: Ist kurz aber ich find's gut +1. (kam hier über low quality queue hin)

Answer (score 4):

Der Chef sagt zu seinem Angestellten: Fälle den Baum. 
Der Angestellte arbeitet nun effektiv, wenn er etwas tut um dieses Ziel zu erreichen. Effizient arbeitet er, wenn er dabei die benötigte Zeit zur Zielerreichung berücksichtigt.

- Beispiel für effektive Arbeit: Mit einem Taschenmesser den Stamm zu bearbeiten bis der Baum fällt
- Beispiel für effiziente Arbeit: Den Baum mit der Kettensäge fällen

Comment: Affektives Beispiel! :)

Comment: Nicht Zeit, sondern einfach nur Rahmenbedingungen oder Vorgaben welcher Art auch immer. Wenn man auf den Benzinverbrauch achten muß, oder aufs Geld, dann ist ein Taschenmesser klar effizienter als eine Kettensäge.

Comment: @RegDwight, guter Hinweis, aber ist nicht Zeit immer auch Geld ;)

Answer (score 3):

Abweichend von den bisher zwei anderen Antworten würde ich gern einwerfen, dass **effektiv** in den meisten Fällen doch auch einen positiven Beiklang hat (außer es wird ausdrücklich mit **effizient** kontrastiert, also etwas , das i.d.R. noch besser ist). Extrem zeitraubende Tätigkeiten wie Baumfällung mit Taschenmesser oder Nagelfeile werden soweit ich sehen kann ausschließlich im Kontext solcher Abgrenzungen zu *effizient* als *effektiv* bezeichnet. Außerhalb solcher erläuternden Vergleiche habe ich das noch nie gesehen. Schließlich geht es bei effektiven Lösungen ja darum, einen *Effekt*, bzw. eher ein Resultat im besten Sinn zu erzielen - mit der Implikation, dass es kein Schildbürgerstreich werden soll.

Normalerweise geht die implizierte Bedeutung von **effektiv** m.E. eher in Richtung "Baumfällen mit einem Bulldozer". Theoretisch denkbar, praktisch umsetzbar, führt absolut zum Ziel - dass es etwas übertrieben erscheint, spielt erst beim Vergleich mit **effizient** eine Rolle.

Answer (score 2):

Effektiv bedeutet, dass die Aufgabe erfüllt wird. Egal ob schnell, langsam, einfach, kompliziert, resourcenschonend oder nicht.

Laut Duden bedeuted [effizient](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/effizient), dass die Aufgabe auf eine "wirtschaftliche Art", also mit möglichst wenig Resourcen, erledigt wird.  Wobei die Resourcen alles sein können. Ein effizienter Arbeiter braucht zum Beispiel weniger Zeit. Ein effizientes Auto weniger Sprit.

[Hier](http://www.zeitblueten.com/news/unterschied-effizient-effektiv/) ist das ganze ein bisschen ausführlicher beschrieben